# Translation of "technically speaking" / What is this villain saying?

Tags: words, nouns, listening

[image]

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy-3KI2eHi4) is a fan-made Japanese version of an English song on a children's show, LazyTown.

I'm trying to find out what the (second) villain was saying (second line) at 0:03. The English translation of the line is above.

> My attempt:
>
> 「おまえら本当の悪{あく}党{とう}か？」
>
> 「**まあ、____にいうと**、いや。」 (0:03)

Comment: Interesting, I thought he said 悪徒. Didn't know the word 悪党. Wonder if one is better than the other in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He says 「まあ、厳密{げんみつ}に言{い}うと、いや。」

"Well, strictly speaking, nope."

Comment: You must be referring to the villain and not the one voicing him, but you might want to use a gender neutral expression :)